# 'jquery' is not a valid script name. The name must end in '.js'

Tags: jquery, asp.net

My ASP.Net project is working well, when suddenly we had a power failure. When I ran my web app, it is now showing a lot of

> Could not load assembly Sanitizer..." then "Could not load "HtmlAgility...

errors. I was able to resolve these previous errors by uninstalling / reinstalling them using *Manage Nuget Package Solutions* inside Visual Studio 2012.

But now I encountered another error:

> 'jquery' is not a valid script name.  The name must end in '.js'."

I tried to do same thing by re-installing the package but it does not work. What should I do to resolve this? I already have a jquery.js file located on my root\Scripts folder. I also added reference to this file inside my  section:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
```

But still it won't work. Please help.

Comment: If it is in the root of your project it's possible you might need an absolute path: `/Scripts/jquery.js`. But that is dependent of where the referring file is.

Comment: I tried that, but it's not working...                           <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" />

Answer (score 27):

By the way guys, I was able to resolve this by installing the `AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery.UI.Combined` and `AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery` packages using the Nuget tool.

Comment: I upgraded the packages you named; this also worked.

Comment: It works (note to others:  the *AND* above is crucial -- both packages required!

Comment: To anyone struggling, there are 2 packages that can be confusing, 1 is jquery.ui.combined and the other is AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery.UI.Combined I got them confused for about 5 to 10 minutes until I realized this, I was installing the wrong one! great answer helps me almost every time a start a new project! haha

Answer (score 5):

Right click on your project and go to ***manage NuGet packages*** and then just install

> AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery.UI.Combined

and

> AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery

packages

Answer (score 3):

Here is working solution

> Open `Global.asax` in your solution

Copy below code just modify your Jquery Version accordingly and paste it   inside Application_Start event of `Global.asax`

```
        ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jquery", new ScriptResourceDefinition
        {
            Path = "~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js",
            DebugPath = "~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js",
            CdnPath = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js",
            CdnDebugPath = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.10.2.js",
            CdnSupportsSecureConnection = true,
            LoadSuccessExpression = "window.jQuery"
        });

    ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jquery.ui.combined", new ScriptResourceDefinition
    {
        Path = "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.2.min.js", 
        DebugPath = "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.2.js", 
        CdnPath = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js", 
        CdnDebugPath = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js", 
        CdnSupportsSecureConnection = true
    });
         ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("bootstrap", new ScriptResourceDefinition
    {
        Path = "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js", 
        DebugPath = "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js", 
        CdnPath = "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js", 
        CdnDebugPath = "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js", 
        CdnSupportsSecureConnection = true
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had to add the two dlls as reference to my project.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for posting your follow-up answer. I got this same error after installing jQuery.UI to a new ASP.NET web forms project based on the new One ASP.NET template in VS.NET 2013 and adding this line to the script manager in the master page:

```
<asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery.ui.combined" />
```

After installing the AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery.UI.Combined NuGet package as you stated, the error was immediately resolved.

Comment: How did you solve this? What is the correct NuGet install order?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation, but mine happened after I tried to update DotNetOpenAuth.Core.  First it said I needed to update NuGet, which I did, then I updated OpenAuth.  After that I started getting the "'jquery' is not a valid script name. The name must end in '.js'.".

If I removed the line adding the jquery bundle, it would happen on jquery-ui etc.

I uninstalled and reinstalled both the AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery and AspNet.ScriptManager.Bootstrap packages (as it would eventually complain about that), and still no luck.

Final step I did was to uninstall and reinstall AjaxControlToolkit from the package manager console and that fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation and already had the script reference (above) but I also needed to make sure that the dll was copied to the local folder.

F4 on AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery and AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery.UI.Combined and set Copy Local to True.

Answer (score 0):

may be a little late to the party but I had the same problem and tried numerous solutions as per above and on other pages.  I would get the error on the last script reference, no matter what that reference was.  I finally decided to remove all the script references and use bundles instead.  For example, default application has the following in bundles.config:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/MsAjaxJs").Include(
    "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjax.js",

ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition(
    "respond",
    new ScriptResourceDefinition
    {
        Path = "~/Scripts/respond.min.js",
        DebugPath = "~/Scripts/respond.js",
    }
);
```

So I changed 'respond' to a bundle instead of a script reference:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/respond").Include(
    "~/Scripts/respond-1.4.2.js"));
```

along with all other script references, and added them to the master page header:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/WebFormsJs") %>
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/MsAjaxJs") %>
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") %>
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui") %>
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/respond") %>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

This removed the error - finally after 2 days - and allowed me to run some basic pages, including the default Register.aspx page.  Not sure what I'll run into next but figured I would pass this along.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my issue. Add this BundleConfig.cs Check your paths.

```
 ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("bootstrap", new ScriptResourceDefinition {
                Path = "~/scripts/bootstrap.min.js",
                DebugPath = "~/scripts/bootstrap.js",
                LoadSuccessExpression = "bootstrap"});
```

And kept this in the ScriptManager on the site.master

```
  <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
```

Follow [this article](https://driftboatdave.com/2014/01/03/jquery-and-bootstrap-hassles/) for more clarity if needed

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your Web.config and the issue will be resolved:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
</appSettings>
```