# Updatepanel is not working: Receiving error: 'respond' is not a valid script name. The name must end in '.js'

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, updatepanel, vs-web-site-project

I'm developing a website for office purpose, there i've to use 'Calendar' tool to pick the date. The calendar will work on a button click, but the problem is whenever the button is clicked to view the calendar the whole page is getting refreshed and the page is going into initial stage, so i tried using updatepanel in the website to restrict this and to refresh only required part of the page. But even though i'm using the correct syntax and everything...still the page is getting refreshed every time.

I'm guessing here that i missed to add any required libraries...So please help me here, if i have to do any pre-configuration to do to use these ajax controllers.

I tried creating one sample website only to check this AJAX functionality by selecting 'WEB API' while creating. here i'm able to use the controllers. I'm not sure how my original website was created during the initial times but the same code is not working here.

I tried adding some packages and .dll files related to Microsoft Ajax but still unable to get.

Currently im getting output like the below

Error: 'respond' is not a valid script name.  The name must end in '.js'.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" runat="server" Height="25px" ImageUrl="images/test_1.png" OnClick="ImageButton3_Click" style="margin-bottom: -7px" Width="25px" />  
<label style="margin-left:10px;">To: </label>  
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" CssClass="tbclass" runat="server" Height="24px" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>  
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton4" runat="server" Height="25px" ImageUrl="images/test_1.png" OnClick="ImageButton4_Click" style="margin-bottom: -7px" Width="25px" />  
<label style="margin-left:10px;">Mettings: </label>  
<asp:dropdownlist runat="server" id="meeting_list_m"> 
    <asp:listitem text="--Select--" value="1"></asp:listitem>
    <asp:listitem text="All Hands Meeting" value="2"></asp:listitem>
</asp:dropdownlist>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="bclear_m" Text="Clear" CssClass="go_sub" onClick="bclear_m_Click" BorderColor="#0066FF" BorderWidth="0px" ForeColor="White" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="go_m" Text="Search" CssClass="go_sub" onClick="go_m_Click" BorderColor="#0066FF" BorderWidth="0px" ForeColor="White" />
<button id="add_button1" class="add_sub" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Add</button>
<asp:Calendar CssClass="calender1_style" ID="Calendar3" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="9pt" ForeColor="Black" Height="190px" OnDayRender="Calendar1_DayRender" OnSelectionChanged="Calendar3_SelectionChanged" Width="280px" NextPrevFormat="ShortMonth">  
<DayHeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="8pt" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />  
<NextPrevStyle Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#333333" Font-Bold="True" VerticalAlign="Bottom" />  
<OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#999999" />  
<SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#333399" ForeColor="White" />  
<TitleStyle CssClass="align-left" BackColor="White" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="12pt" ForeColor="#333399" BorderColor="#CC3399" BorderWidth="0px" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />  
<TodayDayStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />  
</asp:Calendar>   


<asp:Calendar CssClass="calender2_style" ID="Calendar4" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="9pt" ForeColor="Black" Height="190px" OnDayRender="Calendar1_DayRender" OnSelectionChanged="Calendar4_SelectionChanged" Width="280px" NextPrevFormat="ShortMonth">  
<DayHeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="8pt" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />  
<NextPrevStyle Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#333333" Font-Bold="True" VerticalAlign="Bottom" />  
<OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#999999" />  
<SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#333399" ForeColor="White" />  
<TitleStyle CssClass="align-left" BackColor="White" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="12pt" ForeColor="#333399" BorderColor="#CC3399" BorderWidth="0px" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />  
<TodayDayStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />  
</asp:Calendar>  
</ContentTemplate>  
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Try install AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery.UI.Combined and AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery packages using the Nuget tool.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mohammad Alghanem, AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery.dll was already installed, let me try for AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery.UI.Combined and get back to you with update.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the exact solution. First check did you make some changes in bundles.config file. Please share more details or code possible. Also, find this link if helpful
['jquery' is not a valid script name. The name must end in '.js'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14974767/jquery-is-not-a-valid-script-name-the-name-must-end-in-js)

Comment: Hi Parvesh, there is no bundle.config file in my project as it was created as normal website not as application. I've edited my question with code snippet. Please check, let me knwo if i have to make any changes in web.config or packages.config